# How to upgrade alsa-lib to support Syntax 6 configuration files?

Tags: sound, software-installation, 22.04, alsa

I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 installed on Steam Deck but sound does not work since there are missing UCM configuration files for AMD Vangogh (acp5x) drivers which are available in this repository:

https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/tree/master/ucm2/AMD/acp5x

I installed the files but when restarting the `alsa` module I get that the `alsa-lib` package does not support the Syntax 6 configuration files:

```
alsa-lib parser.c:2021:(parse_master_file) Incompatible syntax 6
```

So I have to update `alsa` to a newer version which comes default in Ubuntu 23. But I don't know how to upgrade `alsa-lib` to a newer version while on Ubuntu 22.04.4.

Thanks in advance.